# How do prevent a div from resizing?

Tags: html, css

2 weeks ago I started with learning HTML and CSS, and I really enjoy it.

I've been struggling with getting my footer(div) to resize with my background on my Home page, though. So whenever I zoom in or out the background stays, but the footer(div) moves around. The same when I resize my browser.

It just looks weird. You can say I want to "glue" my div to the background so they resize and move together. It's hard to explain, but try taking a look.

http://www.futureplane.net (the website is still in a work in progress, not finished at all)

It doesn't look great.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Either you need to make all your CSS code in % to, or you can read up about how to make a website respondsive, and that is what i surgest you do.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with an example of the issue you're having?

Comment: You need to add code or the question will be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `min-width: 1200px` set on `#wrapper`. That's creating an issue with the nav area not being flexible if the browser is resized. However, you will need to refactor the `<nav>` elements so they also resize in with the nav/footer bar. You might try using `float` instead of `position` to start with.

Example:

```
#navbar {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 700px;
  margin-top: -155px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: This did help. It's not perfect yet, but I now know what's wrong at what to fix. Thank you very much!